# Why doesnt Android shell have make, configure, tar, etc?

Tags: android, bash, shell, makefile, tar

It is frustratingly limited.

I replaced /system/bin/bash with the bash file from the GNU site but that didnt seem to add the commands I need...

Even busybox doesn't have make or configure..

can anyone help me understand why I dont have **make**?

Comment: Why *would* it have make?  What purpose does that server on a consumer mobile device?  Anyway, off topic since we cannot guess the motivations of the Android designers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do more than just copying bash because "make" is packaged separately.

I recommend to get the corresponding make package . Please refer this http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=26979849 for more information.

Regards,
Jain

Comment: thanks! I think this tutorial will help me build make on my machine (section 5.1) http://autotoolset.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html#The-GNU-build-system